# How can I determine the style, design, and manufacturer of this tile?

Tags: kitchens, new-home

We are extending our kitchen and need to match the backsplash tiles that the previous owner put in. Can someone please give me some information about these tiles? Style/Design/Manufacturer?

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, google image search didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

This will require a lot of leg work, and some phone calls.

The only way to match it up is to go to the tile supply houses in the area and physically compare it to the tile that is in their inventory or samples to order by.
That should be your best shot at it.

While at the various supply houses, I don't mean the big box stores, but don't count them out either for this, there may be a knowledgeable person there that may tell you, "Oh yeah, this looks like such and such of tile, check the store in (fill in name or place here)"

Comment: It actually looks similar to some big-box-store glass tiles, but the problem with big-box-stores is that what they had this (week/month/year) they may not have ever again. If the prior owner's work was recent-ish, you might add those to your round of places to compare. You might also look at specialty on-line glass tile suppliers.

Comment: I just bought a very very close match to this from HD about 3 months ago.  It might be the same thing.